# How to convert some text in paragraph into bold xsl fo?

Tags: xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

This is how my xml looks like:

**xml:**

```
<Documents>
 <Document>
<Note>
  <Header>
    <HeaderText> &lt;b&gt;Need Help?&lt;/b&gt; Contact Our Customer Happiness Team
     by phone  &lt;b&gt;0345 00002662&lt;/b&gt;
     Mon-Fri 9am-7pm
   </HeaderText>
  </Header>
  </Note>
 </Document>
   </Documents>
```

I want to convert some text in HeaderText in bold. E.g **Need Help?** Contact Our Customer Happiness Team
by phone **0345 00002662** Mon-Fri 9am-7pm

**Xslt:**

```
 <fo:table-header text-align="left" border-width="0mm">
    <fo:table-row margin-left="1cm" font-family="Avenir" font-size="14pt">
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block padding-top="0cm">
          <xsl:value-of select="HeaderText" />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&lt;b&gt;Need Help?&lt;/b&gt;` is just text to the XSLT processor and the XSL-FO formatter.

This is similar to [XSLT - How to treat inline/escaped XML within a node as nested nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798465/xslt-how-to-treat-inline-escaped-xml-within-a-node-as-nested-nodes). The advice there doesn't get beyond doing it in two passes or using XSLT 2.0 or 3.0.

If `&lt;b&gt;` is the only non-element that you need to convert into real markup, then you can do it with a recursive template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[contains(., '&lt;b>')]"
              name="unescape-bold">
  <xsl:param name="text" select="." />

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, '&lt;b>'))">
      <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;b>')" />
      <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="substring-before(substring-after($text, '&lt;b>'),
                                     '&lt;/b>')" />
      </fo:inline>
      <xsl:call-template name="unescape-bold">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"
                        select="substring-after($text, '&lt;/b>')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

For your sample, this gives:

```
 <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Need Help?</fo:inline> Contact Our Customer Happiness Team
     by phone  <fo:inline font-weight="bold">0345 00002662</fo:inline>
     Mon-Fri 9am-7pm
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Code:-

```
 <fo:table-header text-align="left" border-width="0mm">
     <fo:table-row margin-left="1cm" font-family="Avenir" font-size="14pt">
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block padding-top="0cm">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-header>

<xsl:template match="bold">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `<xsl:template match="bold">` will not match anything because `&lt;b&gt;Need Help?&lt;/b&gt;` or `&lt;b&gt;0345 00002662&lt;/b&gt;` are only the text and not the element.